# Joining two DataFrames sporadically throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: spark.sql.execution.id is already set"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining two DataFrames created by reading two very large CSV files to compute some statistics. The code is running on a web server and it is triggered by a request, that's why Spark's session is kept always alive without calling `sparkSession.close()`.

**Sporadically**, the code throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: spark.sql.execution.id is already set`. I tried to make sure that the code doesn't get executed more than once at a time and but the problem wasn't resolved.

I am using Spark 2.1.0 and I know that there is an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13747) which would hopefully be resolved in Spark 2.2.0.

Could you please suggest any workarounds in the mean time to avoid this problem?

A simplified version of the code that throws the exception:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("application").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val itemCountry = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(StructType(Array(
    StructField("itemId", IntegerType, false),
    StructField("countryId", IntegerType, false))))
  .csv("/item_country.csv") // This file matches the schema provided
val itemPerformance = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(StructType(Array(
    StructField("itemId", IntegerType, false),
    StructField("date", TimestampType, false),
    StructField("performance", IntegerType, false))))
  .csv("/item_performance.csv") // This file matches the schema provided

itemCountry.join(itemPerformance, itemCountry("itemId") === itemPerformance("itemId"))
  .groupBy("countryId")
  .agg(sum(when(to_date(itemPerformance("date")) > to_date(lit("2017-01-01")), itemPerformance("performance")).otherwise(0)).alias("performance")).show()
```

The stack trace for the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: spark.sql.execution.id is already set
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2778)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2351)
at .... [Custom caller functions]
```

Sample CSV files:

*item_country.csv*

```
itemId,countryId
1,1
2,1
3,2
4,3
```

*item_performance.csv*

```
itemId,date,performance
1,2017-04-15,10
1,2017-04-16,10
1,2017-04-17,10
2,2017-04-15,15
3,2017-04-20,12
4,2017-04-18,18
```